# HIde the all the part except a particular portion for printing using CSS

Tags: css

I have a page in for printing I just want to show the gridview and hide all the controls what i have to do with css.
I am using asp.net Ajax also for my page.
**code fo my page is and the portion which i want to show is div tag name apple**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" Width="1300px" ActiveTabIndex="0">
        <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Engg.(Teaching)
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>January</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>February</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>March</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>April</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>May</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>June</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>July</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>August</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>September</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>October</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>November</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>December</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>2011</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2012</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2013</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2014</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2015</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2016</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2017</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <br>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />

                <div class="apple"> <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id"
                                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnRowDataBound="gv1" ShowFooter="True">
                                <FooterStyle CssClass="FooterStyle" />
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# "detailGenerated.aspx?id="+Eval("id") %>'
                                                Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Act" SortExpression="name">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Button ID="Button9" runat="server" Text="Print" Target="_blank" PostBackUrl='<%# "Default.aspx?id="+Eval("id") %>' />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Designation" HeaderText="designation" SortExpression="designation" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="days" HeaderText="Days" SortExpression="days" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="basic_pay" HeaderText="Basic Pay" SortExpression="basic_pay" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="basic_paid" HeaderText="Basic Paid" SortExpression="basic_paid" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="da" HeaderText="DA" SortExpression="da" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="hra" HeaderText="HRA" SortExpression="hra" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="fma" HeaderText="FMA" SortExpression="fma" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="special_allow" HeaderText="Special Allow." SortExpression="special_allow" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="mobile_allow" HeaderText="Mobile Allow." SortExpression="mobile_allow" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="convey_allow" HeaderText="Convey Allow." SortExpression="convey_allow" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="spl_pay" HeaderText="Spl Pay" SortExpression="spl_pay" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="other_allow" HeaderText="Other Allow." SortExpression="other_allow" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="gross_salary" HeaderText="Gross Salary" SortExpression="gross_salary" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="cpf_ded" HeaderText="CPF Ded." SortExpression="cpf_ded" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="addl_cpf" HeaderText="Addl CPF" SortExpression="addl_cpf" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="cpf_rec" HeaderText="CPF Rec." SortExpression="cpf_rec" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="lic_fee" HeaderText="Lic Fee" SortExpression="lic_fee" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="water_charge" HeaderText="Water Charge" SortExpression="water_charge" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="elec_charge" HeaderText="Elec. Charge" SortExpression="elec_charge" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="i_tax_rec" HeaderText="I Tax Rec" SortExpression="i_tax_rec" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="other_rec" HeaderText="Other Rec" SortExpression="other_rec" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="total_ded" HeaderText="Total Ded" SortExpression="total_ded" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="net_pay" HeaderText="Net Pay" SortExpression="net_pay" />
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:employe %>"
                                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [generated] WHERE (([category] = @category) AND ([wing] = @wing) AND ([year] = @year) AND ([period] = @period)) ORDER BY [basic_pay] DESC">
                                <SelectParameters>
                                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Teaching" Name="category" Type="String" />
                                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Engineering" Name="wing" Type="String" />
                                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList2" Name="year" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                                        Type="String" />
                                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="period" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                                        Type="String" />
                                </SelectParameters>
                            </asp:SqlDataSource>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
              </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:TabPanel>
        <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Engg.(Non-teaching Staff)
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>January</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>February</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>March</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>April</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>May</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>June</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>July</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>August</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>September</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>October</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>November</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>December</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>2011</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2012</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2013</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2014</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2015</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2016</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2017</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <br>
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gv2" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
                            <FooterStyle CssClass="FooterStyle" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Designation" HeaderText="designation" SortExpression="designation" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="days" HeaderText="Days" SortExpression="days" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="basic_pay" HeaderText="Basic Pay" SortExpression="basic_pay" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="basic_paid" HeaderText="Basic Paid" SortExpression="basic_paid" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="da" HeaderText="DA" SortExpression="da" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="hra" HeaderText="HRA" SortExpression="hra" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="fma" HeaderText="FMA" SortExpression="fma" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="special_allow" HeaderText="Special Allow." SortExpression="special_allow" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="mobile_allow" HeaderText="Mobile Allow." SortExpression="mobile_allow" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="convey_allow" HeaderText="Convey Allow." SortExpression="convey_allow" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="spl_pay" HeaderText="Spl Pay" SortExpression="spl_pay" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="other_allow" HeaderText="Other Allow." SortExpression="other_allow" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="gross_salary" HeaderText="Gross Salary" SortExpression="gross_salary" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="cpf_ded" HeaderText="CPF Ded." SortExpression="cpf_ded" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="addl_cpf" HeaderText="Addl CPF" SortExpression="addl_cpf" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="cpf_rec" HeaderText="CPF Rec." SortExpression="cpf_rec" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="lic_fee" HeaderText="Lic Fee" SortExpression="lic_fee" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="water_charge" HeaderText="Water Charge" SortExpression="water_charge" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="elec_charge" HeaderText="Elec. Charge" SortExpression="elec_charge" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="i_tax_rec" HeaderText="I Tax Rec" SortExpression="i_tax_rec" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="other_rec" HeaderText="Other Rec" SortExpression="other_rec" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="total_ded" HeaderText="Total Ded" SortExpression="total_ded" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="net_pay" HeaderText="Net Pay" SortExpression="net_pay" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:employe %>"
                            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [generated] WHERE (([category] = @category) AND ([wing] = @wing) AND ([year] = @year) AND ([period] = @period)) ORDER BY [basic_pay] DESC">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Non-Teaching" Name="category" Type="String" />
                                <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Engineering" Name="wing" Type="String" />
                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList4" Name="year" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                                    Type="String" />
                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList3" Name="period" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                                    Type="String" />
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button2" EventName="Click" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:TabPanel>
        <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel3" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Engg.(Admn. Staff)
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>January</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>February</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>March</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>April</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>May</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>June</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>July</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>August</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>September</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>October</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>November</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>December</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList6" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>2011</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2012</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2013</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2014</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2015</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2016</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2017</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <br>
                <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gv3" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3">
                            <FooterStyle CssClass="FooterStyle" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Designation" HeaderText="designation" SortExpression="designation" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="days" HeaderText="Days" SortExpression="days" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="basic_pay" HeaderText="Basic Pay" SortExpression="basic_pay" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="basic_paid" HeaderText="Basic Paid" SortExpression="basic_paid" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="da" HeaderText="DA" SortExpression="da" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="hra" HeaderText="HRA" SortExpression="hra" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="fma" HeaderText="FMA" SortExpression="fma" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="special_allow" HeaderText="Special Allow." SortExpression="special_allow" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="mobile_allow" HeaderText="Mobile Allow." SortExpression="mobile_allow" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="convey_allow" HeaderText="Convey Allow." SortExpression="convey_allow" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="spl_pay" HeaderText="Spl Pay" SortExpression="spl_pay" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="other_allow" HeaderText="Other Allow." SortExpression="other_allow" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="gross_salary" HeaderText="Gross Salary" SortExpression="gross_salary" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="cpf_ded" HeaderText="CPF Ded." SortExpression="cpf_ded" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="addl_cpf" HeaderText="Addl CPF" SortExpression="addl_cpf" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="cpf_rec" HeaderText="CPF Rec." SortExpression="cpf_rec" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="lic_fee" HeaderText="Lic Fee" SortExpression="lic_fee" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="water_charge" HeaderText="Water Charge" SortExpression="water_charge" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="elec_charge" HeaderText="Elec. Charge" SortExpression="elec_charge" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="i_tax_rec" HeaderText="I Tax Rec" SortExpression="i_tax_rec" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="other_rec" HeaderText="Other Rec" SortExpression="other_rec" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="total_ded" HeaderText="Total Ded" SortExpression="total_ded" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="net_pay" HeaderText="Net Pay" SortExpression="net_pay" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:employe %>"
                            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [generated] WHERE (([category] = @category) AND ([wing] = @wing) AND ([year] = @year) AND ([period] = @period)) ORDER BY [basic_pay] DESC">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Administrative" Name="category" Type="String" />
                                <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Engineering" Name="wing" Type="String" />
                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList6" Name="year" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                                    Type="String" />
                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList5" Name="period" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                                    Type="String" />
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button3" EventName="Click" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:TabPanel>


            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:TabPanel>
    </asp:TabContainer>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

in a CSS file `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="filename.css" media="print" />`

```
body * {
   display: none;
}

div#apple {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: By writing this css on printer nothing appears it shows blank page.